# Passing large string from Android webview to native is incredibly slow

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, interface

I'm using a JavaScript interface to communicate with a JavaScript library (running in an Android webview) and the native side. This works great, except when sending over large, stringified JSON objects. It is incredibly slow, taking as long as 20 seconds. Is there a way to remedy this?

Edit: here's the JS Interface on the native side:

```
public class JSInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JSInterface  (Activity act) {
        this.activity = act;
    }

    public void someMethod(String message) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
            // Do stuff...
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            showError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how the webview uses it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        JSInterface.someMethod(JSON.stringify(largeJsonObject));})
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err.message);
    }
});
```

The Webview is initialized like this:

```
WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = ProjectData.mainWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
JSInterface mainJSInterface = new JSInterface(this);
mainWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mainJSInterface, "JSInterface");
mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mainWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web_view/index.html");
```

Comment: Can you put your code?

Comment: Sure, I added it. :) The event is being called not only on document.ready, by the way, but after the page is loaded and on click events.

Comment: Ok, this is odd.....the delay has drastically reduced without any changes. It's still there but only a brief second. But I'm positive it was occurring simply by sending over large strings.

Comment: Ok, fascinating...this seems to be caused by running the app in debug mode. Otherwise, there's only the brief delay which might not be related to the webview at all but is caused by other code. Something about debugging slows it down greatly when sending over large strings.